# Python Functions and Variables - Learn Python The Hard way ex19

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, variables

Doesn't this function call variables from the script?, which goes against what Zed Shaw has stated...

I have put the comments in myself, my problem is this:

Zed Shaw states:

> The variables in a function are not connected to variables in a script

But from what i see, the function is at the top with indentation, then when indentation starts its creating variables which are then linked to the function.

Doesn't this function call variables from the script?

I couldn't find a suitable answer: could someone elaborate on this bit of script and tell me if i am viewing it wrongly?

```
# This is the function with declared variables inside
def cheese_and_crackers(cheese_count, boxes_of_crackers):
    print  "You have %d cheeses!" % cheese_count
    print "You have %d boxes of crackers!"  % boxes_of_crackers
    print "Man thats enough for a party!"
    print "Get a Blanket. \n"

# This declares the amounts in the functions variables
print "We can just give the function numbers directly:"
cheese_and_crackers (20, 30)

# This variable sets the amounts
print "OR, we can use variables from our script:"
amount_of_cheese = 10
amount_of_crackers = 50
#This variable combines the two above and stores it in a single variable for the function to call
cheese_and_crackers(amount_of_cheese, amount_of_crackers)

# This uses the function, but has predefined variables with maths
print "We can even do math inside too:"
cheese_and_crackers(10 + 20, 5 + 6)
#This combines variables with maths
print "And we can combine the two, variables and math:"
cheese_and_crackers (amount_of_cheese + 100, amount_of_crackers + 1000)
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: My question is: Doesnt this function call variables from the script?, which goes against what Zed Shaw has stated, otherwise please explain...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variables are not at any time connected to the function parameters other than the fact that they are passed as arguments to the function. Calling `foo(bar)` doesn't connect `bar` to `foo()`, it merely passes the value of `bar` as the first parameter of the function. If that parameter also happens to be called "bar" then that is coincidence.